# How to design REST API for email sending service?

Tags: rest

How to design REST API for email sending service by using POST, GET, PUT, DELETE?

```
send: POST - /email
retrieve: GET - /email/{id}
delete: DELETE - /email/{id}
```

Is it the correct way of designing REST API? I feel like it's not intuitive to map POST to the action "send".

Comment: "_it's not intuitive to map POST to the action "send"_"? So what would you map instead?

Comment: Normally "POST" is used for creating a new instance. If there are more than one action ("send immediate", "send", or other action types), we are running out of HTTP verb.

Comment: No, we are not. If simple resources are not enough, use controllers. I recommend reading http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do. As far as your issue is concerned, you can first add a resource and then send it using some controller.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The scheme you have given is correct. Alternatively you can use controllers to perform some more complex actions.

In your case it can look like this:

```
(action)           (verb)   (URI)                             (type)
create:            POST   - /emails                         - collection
retrieve:          GET    - /email/{id}                     - resource
update:            PUT    - /email/{id}                     - resource
delete:            DELETE - /email/{id}                     - resource
send immediately:  POST   - /email/{id}/sendImmediately     - controller
just send:         POST   - /email/{id}/send                - controller
do something else: POST   - /email/{id}/someOtherActionType - controller
```

Note new controllers and the change creation works. The latter is rather subjective, but reasonable (as you cannot really access the URL of "no actual email" like I would interpret "`/email`" without "`{id}`" part).

Additional resources:

- [REST API Design Rulebook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do)

Comment: I thought there should be no "verb" in REST API? IMO REST API should only contains "noun".

Comment: @janetsmith: Please do not reinvent the wheel, "verbs" have been existing in HTTP for a long time. If you are referring to the URI, not the verb, then it should be rather irrelevant to the client what string it uses (is it really reasonable for a computer to have a preference of "`/email/{id}/sendingQueue`" instead of "`/email/{id}/send`"?). The controllers are the type of resources that are function-oriented and you are not actually able to perform some actions if you stick to more "static" types of resources. Did I understand correctly, that your objections are about usage of controllers?

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the URL naming. Using "verb" in URL seems like SOA style, while REST api is ROA (Resource oriented architecture) style. However, your "controller" style makes it easier to map to my program, because it looks like object-oriented style.

Comment: @janetsmith: I believe "no verb, only nouns" is overly simplified approach, probably to teach people REST. The idea is indeed to use documents (kind of resources) that you can easily edit and that are aggregated within collections (that are also kind of resources). But to have more advanced, function-style features, you need controllers (another kind of resources). Not mentioning that eg. Ruby on Rails uses verbs within the URLs, but they are proud of being RESTful ([see here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)). Using verbs in the URL strings does not make you less RESTful.

Comment: Another approach could be POST the email ID to a /queue resource. The queue could accept a priority value to determine where the email goes in the queue. Also how you are storing the state or status of the email? If there's a status value in the email object, the queue controller can PATCH the /email resource once the sending is complete.

Comment: Lets say we are dealing with accounts instead of emails. And we have a POST route like: `accounts/`. In your definition above this would probably be a "resource" type. But what if this route also has a "controller-like-behavior", like sending out an email to the newly created account owner. Would this be called a resource or a controller?

Comment: @AndersÖstman: No, it would be a _collection_. When creating resource instance, there would be a side effect not visible to API client. That is all, plain and simple.